# Can I bypass number-limit while specifying the port for socket library in Python?

Tags: python, sockets

So I was selecting the port number for a Python backdoor. When I kept a large number like 5979543, it said it was invalid.
So... anyway to bypass that restriction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So... anyway to bypass that restriction?

No. The port number in the TCP and UDP header is 16 bit which allows for a maximum port number of 65535. No way to assign a higher port number since it cannot be represented in the communication packets.